# Is Python Cookbook for python 2.4 applicable to python 2.7.5?

Tags: programming-languages, python, versioning

My college has a course on Introduction to programming using python and we are using Python 2.7.5.

I would like to know if it will be helpful to read Python Cookbook which is for python 2.4?

There are no separate cookbooks for python 2.7.x, to my knowledge. But, are there any similar books? There is a later edition to python cookbook for Python 3, but it turns out that python 3 and python 2 are quite different.

Comment: Don't worry, go with that as fundamentals should be same with all Python 2.0 and up books

Comment: Python 2.7.x and 3 are indeed quite different in some respects. However, you could use this as an opportunity to get to know both ways of doing things. That is, read how to do it in 3 and if it doesn't work in 2.7.x, figure out why. It will give you a much better understanding and help you remember as well as prepare for the near future, because 3 is gaining ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to know if it will be helpful to read python Cookbook which is for python 2.4?

**In short:** Yes, start with the book that you have. Later, i would definitely look and  cover the points introduced in [**what's new in Python 2.7**](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html) .

The fundamentals of the Python language are going to stay same. There will not be big shifts/changes between 2.4 and 2.7 versions. However, new features of language might be added in a beta version.

What you need to be aware of are the core versions (2.0, 3.0, etc..) of the programming language. Because, they may introduce much efficient or renewed approach on how to build the app.

Comment: ...and "What's new in Python 2.5" and "What's new in Python 2.6".